# Ask user to input circle radius and draw a circle using that radius JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, geometry

I am trying to get the user input as a value inside the width and height of the circle in the paint method. The problem is that I cannot use the value assigned to the double r variable. The idea is to somehow replace the 200 (height value) and 200 (width value) with the variable r, so the user can decide the radius. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Circle extends JFrame {

    public Circle(){
        setTitle("Drawing a Circle");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawOval(150, 150, 200, 200);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Input radius of circle: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double r = sc.nextDouble();

        new Circle();

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are asking for `r` and then never use it? Would not your `Circle` object need it?

Comment: Note that there is an existing class (java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D) which has several advantages to the class you've created. One of these advantages is that it implements Shape and as such can be drawn / filled in directly using Graphics2D.draw and Graphics2D.fill

Comment: If you're extending `JFrame` you should invoke a super constructor in your no-arg constructor `Circle()` - in your case you could use `super("Drawing a Circle");` and eliminate the `setTitle` call.

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor so that it receives the radius (I've changed to an int since you can't draw a partial pixel anyways). Store that value in an instance variable so that it can be accessed from the paint event:

```
public class Circle extends JFrame {

    private int radius; // <-- instance (non-static) var to hold radius

    public Circle(int radius){ // <-- constructor receives an int
        this.radius = radius; // <-- store the local var in the class var
        setTitle("Drawing a Circle");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        // use "radius" somehow in your call to drawOval()
        g2d.drawOval(150, 150, radius*2, radius*2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Input radius of circle: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r = sc.nextInt(); // <-- changed to int
        new Circle(r); // <-- pass in "r"
    }
}
```